# Prove that for all real $x < 1$ the following equation $x^9+4x < 3+2x^5 $ is true

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I'm asked (for homework which isn't graded but instead the basis of a quiz) to directly prove that for all real x < 1 the following equation  $x^9+4x < 3+2x^5 $ is true

I am VERY new to proofs.

I don't see a way to simplify this into ( something )^2 + something else.

I'd also be very thankful if someone were to have a complete answer

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Let $f(x) = x^9 - 2x^5 + 4x - 3$. Check $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} f(x) < 0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty} f(x) < 0$, and check that $f'(x) > 0$ ($f'(x)$ can be made a quadratic polynomial by a suitable substitution)

Comment: Could you please solve it fully, because I had been trying for several days with no success, I will be very grateful=)

Comment: It's quite trivial after that. Which part are you stuck on - (i) Showing the above three statements are true or (ii) Showing the result from the above three statements?

Comment: (ii) Showing the result from the above three statements

Comment: @lokey8573 is  the sign of $x$ known?

Comment: not , not stated

Comment: That's actually a standard result. Note that the global maxima of a differentiable function will occur either at the endpoints or at the local maxima. So what those three statements imply is that the global maxima is $< 0$ (that's what the 3 statements check - no local maxima and negative at endpoints) which means that the function is always $<0$.

Comment: I think you meant *inequality* when you typed *equation*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(x) := x^9 - 2x^5 + 4x - 3$. We want to show $f(x) < 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ satisfying $x < 1$. First of all, $f$ (being a polynomial) is differentiable everywhere. We have
$$f'(x) = 9x^8 - 10x^4 + 4$$
To understand the behavior of $f'(x)$, let $g(t) = 9t^2 - 10t + 4$ (I am really just substituting $x^4 =: t$). The discriminant of $g$ is $100 - 4\cdot 4 \cdot 9 < 0$, so $g$ has no real roots. As the leading coefficient of $g$ is positive, $g$ is always positive, i.e., $g(t) > 0$ for all $t$. Therefore, $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$, implying that $f$ is strictly increasing.

Since $f$ is strictly increasing, we have $f(x) < f(1)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ satisfying $x < 1$. The claim follows from $f(1) = 0$.